# Group theory and electronic energy bands in solids books

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, group-theory, crystals, electronic-band-theory

I am trying to study about group theory and energy bands to try and learn and understand this scary graph:

[image]

So far I'm having serious difficulties understanding the subject of  Symmetrization of Nearly Free Electron Wave Functions, and the materials I found about this subject is not understandable at best. If someone have any recommendations for good places or books to study the subject from it would be great. I do have backgroup in mathematics and quantum materials, and I know a bit of symmetry as well. So I don't need to restudy the definition of Hamiltonian or wave vector.

Comment: Do you know how to find positions in the unit cell?By the way this seems like a solid crystal made of many different types of atoms.

Comment: I know the concept of primitive lattice vectors and unit cell. Know what fcc bcc and sc means.

Comment: Start with Ashcroft and Mermin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modern book guiding step-by-step in the world of applications of group theory and group representation theory to the study of electronic states is
*Dresselhaus, M. S., Dresselhaus, G., & Jorio, A. (2007). "Group theory: application to the physics of condensed matter." Springer Science & Business Media*. It has an intimidating size ( almost 800 pages ), but it is complete and starts from the very beginning, introducing all the relevant results of group theory, applying them to electronic and vibrational states of molecules, and arriving, in Ch.13, to the Group of the Wave Vector and Bloch's Theorem.
Then, it continues with many examples, in particular for cubic crystals, without leaving anything unexplained. More advanced topics like the inclusion of the spin and Magnetic Groups are also thoroughly discussed with (solved) problems. Applications to new materials like fullerenes and carbon nanotubes are also present.

I find it definitely more complete and up-to-date than the historical reference for applications of Group theory to electronic states of crystal: *Bassani, F. G., & Parravicini, G. P. (1975). "Interband transitions and optical properties. Electronic States and Optical Transitions In Solids."*